# Toolbar title not changing in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to set the title of Toolbar in Android but the app crashes (null pointer exception). I have tried many stackoverflow same question but none seemed to work for me. I used the code below

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBarDataProvider);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Notice");
```

**Logcat**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference at com.akapoor.kiittimetabletest1.Notice.onCreate(Notice.java:31)
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.akapoor.kiittimetabletest1.Notice">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_data_provider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvServerText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bServer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Refresh" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar_data_provider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolBarDataProvider"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: What style are you using in your manifest for this activity?

Comment: Does your activity class extend AppCompatActivity?

Comment: there are "exclusive" methods `setSupportActionBar` and `getSupportActionBar` used, from `AppCompatActivity`...

Answer (score 0):

so you don't have `Toolbar`... maybe show us your code for style or xml layout for this `Activity`

edit:
maybe there is some id overwritting, when you using

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
```

this is your new id for your `Toolbar` (first view in included in separated files). try to use `merge` (wrap whole `Toolbar`) or just do not set new id in include

more [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Though setSupportActionBar you pass null parameter. Thus you **toolbar** is **null**. In this way we can make a conclusion that **findViewById** cannot find view with id **toolbarDataProvider**. I suggest you need to check validity of your id. Or provide information about your xml.

**EDITED**

So, as I said you don't have id **toolbarDataProvider**. When you use include tag you import view described in other xml, but you can override attributes to it. In your case you override id attribute from **toolbarDataProvider** to **include**. Try to change your code to see if it works correctly:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.include);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Notice");
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you did not set your toolbar as a SupportActionctionBar, because you included it. To acces included layout you need to:

1) Get included layout:

```
View icludedLayout = findViewById(R.id.include);
```

2) Get Toolbar from it:

```
View toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBarDataProvider);
```

**EDIT**

If you haven't mistaken in question, and your tollbar xml file is named as Toolbar.xml you need to change include tag to:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> You must set the xml file name for `layout` attribute (Which in your case the xml file name is `Toolbar`)

**EDITED**

Replace this:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_data_provider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

With the following code (In this code, I set the id of `include` tag to `toolBarDataProvider` instead of `include`):

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolBarDataProvider"
    layout="@layout/Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And the `Toolbar.XML` file should contains the following code (The `toolbar` id attribute is not needed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very very late answer but for anyone still looking for help on this question... assign your toolbar the id of `include`. This worked for me, also be sure to set your toolbar in styles to NoActionBar.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.include);
```